# Xcode not allowing adding of new outlet

Tags: xcode, swift, outlet

When i control click on any of the objects in my view controller and try to drag them to the viewcontroller it wont seem to let me add any of the objects as outlets or actions. Any idea whats causing that?

Comment: Is your view controller in interface builder linked to your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you are dragging your outlets to corresponding class specified in your controller and it should be .h file